# Does Find My iPhone upload its location when connected to iTunes via USB?

Tags: ios, find-my-iphone

If Find My iPhone is active for my iPhone, will it upload its location if the iPhone is connected to an Internet-connected PC or Mac using a USB cable?

Normally I would imagine it would ask for a password or 'trust this computer' for example, but since Find My iPhone is enabled for the iPhone it would make sense if it would just use the Internet connection to pass on its location details to iCloud so I can trace it.

My iPhone is stolen but it had a PIN code on it, but at the same time it happened abroad so data roaming was switched off and it is very unlikely it will automatically connect to an unknown Wi-Fi network for passing on location data obviously.

Answer (score -1):

No, the iPhone does not update its location when plugged in. However, the iPhone will send its location to Apple when the battery gets to a critical level *as long as it has an Internet connection*.